Use touchID instead of password for apps asking for elevated permissions?
Even tough touchID can be used for many things, when apps want to install some components, a password prompt still pops up.
Is there a way to use touchID for this also?
This is more convenient, and more importantly, it avoids part of the problem described here: What stops fake password prompts?. If touchID is used, then the password is less likely to leak due to fake password prompts, and fake password prompts are easier to identify.
